# How to find the p,d,q values selected in auto_arima() Python?

Tags: python, arima, pyramid-arima

I would like to run auto_arima() on a training set and then use the same selected p,d,q values to evaluate arima() on a test set.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about [this `auto_arima()`](http://www.alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/0.9.0/modules/generated/pyramid.arima.auto_arima.html), it apparently

> returns a fitted ARIMA model

i.e. [an instance of this `ARIMA` class](http://www.alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/0.9.0/modules/generated/pyramid.arima.ARIMA.html#pyramid.arima.ARIMA).

You can then directly use that class, or if you really do need the parameters, see the [`get_params()` method](http://www.alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/0.9.0/modules/generated/pyramid.arima.ARIMA.html#pyramid.arima.ARIMA.get_params).